# How to switch between two sets of attribute values, depending on an internal state?

Tags: python-3.x, class, properties, state, getter

I have a class holding some scientific data. Depending on an internal state, the values of this class can appear as normalized (i.e. unitless), or non-normalized. The values are always stored as normalized, but if the object is set in non-normalized status, the user-accessible properties (and methods) will give the non-normalized values. This way the class appears as non-normalized, while there's no need to duplicate the stored values.

Right now I implemented this using getters. While it works, it gives a lot of repeating structure, and I wonder if there's a more Pythonic way of managing this without overcomplicating things.

**Am I doing this right? Is there a more elegant way to switch between two sets of data in a similar fashion?**

```
class CoolPhysicsData(object):
    def __init__(self, lambda0, *args, normed=False):
        self.lambda0 = lambda0     # some normalization factor (wavelength of some wave)
        self.normalized = normed      # user can change this state as he pleases
        self._normed_tmin, self._normed_tmax, self._normed_r = self.calculate_stuffs(*args)
        ...

    @property
    def tmin(self):
        if self.normalized:
            return self._normed_tmin
        else:
            return denormalize(self.lambda0, self._normed_tmin, unit_type="time")

    @property
    def tmax(self):
        if self.normalized:
            return self._normed_tmax
        else:
            return denormalize(self.lambda0, self._normed_tmax, unit_type="time")

    @property
    def r(self):
        if self.normalized:
            return self._normed_r
        else:
            return denormalize(self.lambda0, self._normed_r, unit_type="len")

    ...  # about 15 getters alike these
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to avoid using properties, and implement `__getattr__`, `__setattr__` and `__delattr__`. Since you need to know which quantity you're denormalizing, there's really no way to escape definitions: these must be handcoded somewhere. I'd do this way:

```py
class CoolPhysicsData:
    def _get_normalization_params(self, value):
        # set up how individual properties should be denormalized..
        params = {
            # 'property_name' : (norm_factor, norm_value, 'unit_type')
            'tmin': (self.lambda0, self._normed_tmin, 'time'),
            'tmax': (self.lambda0,  self._normed_tmax, 'time'),
            'r': (self.lambda0, self._normed_r, 'len'),
        }
        return params[value]
```

and I would implement `__getattr__` something like this:

```py
...
    def __getattr__(self, value):
        # extract the parameters needed
        norm_factor, normed_value, unit_type = self._get_normalization_params(f'{value}')
        if self.normed:
            return normed_value
        else:
            return self.denormalize(norm_factor, normed_value, unit_type)
...
```

Note that you might want to write `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` too.

---

One little addition: [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) might be useful to you. I'm not sure if `*args` in your `__init__` function is the exact signature, or you just simplified for the sake of the example. If you have known arguments (no varargs), this can be easily turned into a `dataclass`.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class CoolPhysicsData:
    lambda0: float
    normed: bool = field(default=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        # set up some test values for simplicity
        # of course you can run custom calculations here..
        self._normed_tmin = 1
        self._normed_tmax = 2
        self._normed_r = 3

    def __getattr__(self, value):
        norm_factor, normed_value, unit_type = self._get_normalization_params(f'{value}')
        if self.normed:
            return normed_value
        else:
            return self.denormalize(norm_factor, normed_value, unit_type)

#     you may want to implement the following methods too:

#     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
#         # your custom logic here
#         ...
        
#     def __delattr__(self, name):
#         # your custom logic here
#         ...
  
    def denormalize(self, v1, v2, v3):
        # just for simplicity
        return 5
        
    def _get_normalization_params(self, value):
        # setup how individual properties should be denormalized..
        params = {
            # 'property_name' : (norm_factor, norm_value, 'unit_type')
            'tmin': (self.lambda0, self._normed_tmin, 'time'),
            'tmax': (self.lambda0,  self._normed_tmax, 'time'),
            'r': (self.lambda0, self._normed_r, 'len'),
        }
        return params[value]
```

Is it more pythonic? It's up to you to decide. It surely takes away some repetition, but you introduce a little more complexity, and - in my opinion - it's more prone to bugs.

Comment: Great answer! Wouldn't work for me that well, as the actual class is much more complex - but a nice way to solve the problem I proposed in my question.